# C++ multithreaded access of boolean member

Tags: c++, foreach, c++17, mutex, atomic

Due to low latency requirement, I'm using parallel execution of for_each to recognize intention of a sentence (a set of strings). I learnt before that there is no need for mutex to protect bool or any data type that its size is less than one byte. So I'm asking if accessing boolean member Tag.m_Found is thread safe? Otherwise, should I use atomic or mutex?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
struct Tag{
    const std::unordered_set<std::string> m_Context;
    const std::string m_Name;
    volatile bool m_Found;
    Tag(const std::unordered_set<std::string> context, const std::string name)
        : m_Context(context)
        , m_Name(name)
        , m_Found(false)
        {}
    Tag(const Tag & tag) = delete;
    Tag(Tag && tag) = default;
    Tag & operator=(const Tag & tag) = delete;
};
int main(){
    const std::set<std::string> input = {"hello", "my", "son"};
    std::list<Tag> intentions;
    intentions.emplace_back(Tag({"hello", "Hi", "morning"}, "greeting"));
    intentions.emplace_back(Tag({"father", "mother", "son"}, "family"));
    intentions.emplace_back(Tag({"car", "bus", "airplan"}, "transportation"));
    for_each( std::execution::par
            , std::begin(input)
            , std::end(input)
            , [& intentions](const std::string & input_element)
                {
                    for_each( std::execution::par
                            , std::begin(intentions)
                            , std::end(intentions)
                            , [& input_element](Tag & intention){
                                if(!intention.m_Found){
                                    intention.m_Found = intention.m_Context.find(input_element)!=intention.m_Context.end();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
        );
    for_each( std::execution::seq
            , std::begin(intentions)
            , std::end(intentions)
            , [](Tag & intention){
                if(intention.m_Found){
                    std::cout<<intention.m_Name;
                }
            }
        );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I learnt before that there is no need for mutex to protect bool or any data type that its size is less than one byte."  Sorry, but that is flat-out wrong.  Concurrent read/write access to any object requires either a mutex (or other synchronization) or else `std::atomic`; otherwise you have a data race which is undefined behavior.  There is no exception for `bool`, nor based on the size of the object, and `volatile` does not help.

Comment: Unrelated: volatile doesn't help with multithreading. Why do you even have it?

Comment: Also too, there are no data types with size less than one byte.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Except maybe bitfields, and for them the atomicity situation is even worse as every write must RMW.

Comment: @NateEldredge Bit fields are not types.

Comment: This is a wrong use of `volatile`. Use `std::atomic<bool>` or the like. That will (at least) get memory barriers “right” in case if the tag is supposed to have release/acquire or produce/consume semantics.

Comment: Thanks for all clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is if adding "std::mutex m_Found_access;" or making "atomic_bool m_Found;" the default move constructor is deleted so I need to define a move constructor for Tag. And m_Found should only be set to true to avoid race condition (as @Nate Eldredge mentioned). The code becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
struct Tag{
    const std::unordered_set<std::string> m_Context;
    const std::string m_Name;
    std::atomic_bool m_Found;
    Tag(const std::unordered_set<std::string> context, const std::string name)
        : m_Context(context)
        , m_Name(name)
        , m_Found(false)
        {}
    Tag(const Tag & tag) = delete;
    Tag & operator=(const Tag & tag) = delete;
    Tag(Tag && tag) : m_Context(std::move(tag.m_Context))
                    , m_Name(std::move(tag.m_Name))
                    , m_Found(static_cast< bool >(tag.m_Found))
                    {}
};
int main(){
    const std::set<std::string> input = {"hello", "my", "son"};
    std::list<Tag> intentions;
    intentions.emplace_back(Tag({"hello", "Hi", "morning"}, "greeting"));
    intentions.emplace_back(Tag({"father", "mother", "son"}, "family"));
    intentions.emplace_back(Tag({"car", "bus", "airplan"}, "transportation"));
    for_each( std::execution::par
            , std::begin(input)
            , std::end(input)
            , [& intentions](const std::string & input_element)
                {
                    for_each( std::execution::par
                            , std::begin(intentions)
                            , std::end(intentions)
                            , [& input_element](Tag & intention){
                                if(!intention.m_Found){
                                    if(intention.m_Context.find(input_element)!=intention.m_Context.end()){
                                        intention.m_Found = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
        );
    for_each( std::execution::seq
            , std::begin(intentions)
            , std::end(intentions)
            , [](Tag & intention){
                if(intention.m_Found){
                    std::cout<<intention.m_Name;
                }
            }
        );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note you can also optimize a little by making your accesses `std::memory_order_relaxed`, since the flag does not control access to any shared resource nor require ordering with anything.  You can also use `std::atomic_flag` instead of `std::atomic<bool>` so that it is guaranteed to be lock-free, though in practice on most implementations they are the same.

Comment: Thanks @Nate Eldredge, I have updated the code to avoid race condition.